# Using pretrained Word2Vec model for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

I am using a pretrained Word2Vec model for tweets to create vectors for each word. https://www.fredericgodin.com/software/.  I will then compute the average of this and use a classifier to determine sentiment.

My training data is very large and the pretrained Word2Vec model has been trained on millions of tweets, with dimensionality = 400. My problem is that it is taking too long to give vectors to the words in my training data. Is there a way to reduce the time taken to build the word vectors?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you mean by "too long".

Looking up individual word-vectors from a pre-existing model should be very fast: it's a simple in-memory lookup of the word to the array index (from a dict), then an access of that array-index.

If it's slow for you, perhaps you've loaded a model larger than your available RAM? In that case, operation might be relying on much-slower virtual memory (paging working memory to and from slower disk). With these kinds of models, where access is very random across locations, you never ever want to do this. If it's happening, you should get more RAM or use a smaller model.